# gem install refinerycms it does not work (windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, refinerycms

Prerequisites before install refinerycms

1. install Ruby and Rubygems
2. install database (mysql)
3. install ImageMagick last version

All prerequisites were installed correctly. Next step install refinerycms

"gem install refinerycms" ,then does no work and i get this error

could not find a valid gem ´refinerycms' ()= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - ssl_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Question is not clear. Show the steps/commands your are executing and exactly where the error occurs.

Comment: Can you access https://rubygems.org from your current connection?

Comment: From my browser i can , but if i try update from console with  "gem update --system" I get error

Comment: Seems like an SSL error when connecting to rubygems.org to me.

Comment: taking into account the "SSL" error, i can fix change certificate like this:
   

 gem sources -r https://rubygems.org, 
 gem sources -a http://rubygems.org, 
 gem update --system, 
 gem sources -r http://rubygems.org,  
 gem sources -a https://rubygems.org,  

and finally "gem install refinerycms" run

Comment: solved? if not, what is your rubygems version? You can find that by entering this `gem --version` in command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps should help

- Find out your gem version using `gem --version`
- Depending on your version, download an update from one of the links
  below:

Running 1.8.x: download [1.8.30](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v1.8.30)

Running 2.0.x: donwload    [2.0.15](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.0.15)

Running 2.2.x: download [2.2.3](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/releases/tag/v2.2.3)

- Move the file to the root of your drive(easiest to point to from cmd) `C:\`
- Now using command prompt, enter the following:

`C:\>gem install --local C:\rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem`

NB: Change `rubygems-update-1.8.30.gem`
 to the name of the file you downloaded

- Now enter this too when that is completed:

`C:\>update_rubygems --no-ri --no-rdoc`

- After this, `gem --version` should report the new update version you downloaded.
- You can now safely uninstall `rubygems-update gem`:

`C:\>gem uninstall rubygems-update -x`

Source: [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88)

Answer (score 0):

I can fix this error, change certificate like this:

- gem sources -r rubygems.org
- gem sources -a rubygems.org
- gem update --system
- gem sources -r rubygems.org
- gem sources -a rubygems.org

  and finally "gem install refinerycms" run

thanks for the help everyone!!